# Anything-sync-daemon is not making backup snapshots

Tags: ramdisk, cache-directory

I have Anything-sync-daemon ("asd") installed and minimally configured according to this page:

[Anything-sync-daemon - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Anything-sync-daemon)

Running `asd p` gives the following output:

```
Anything-sync-daemon v5.85 on Arch Linux

Systemd service is currently active.
Systemd resync service is currently active.
Overlayfs technology is currently inactive.

Asd will manage the following per /run/asd.conf settings:

owner/group id:     myuser/1000
target to manage:   /home/myuser/.cache
sync target:        /home/myuser/.cache-backup_asd
tmpfs target:       /tmp/asd-myuser/home/myuser/.cache
dir size:           3.3G
recovery dirs:      none
```

Executing `cat /etc/asd.conf` shows everything at default values except WHATTOSYNC:

```
WHATTOSYNC=(
    '/home/myuser/.cache'
)

# The default is to save the most recent 5 crash recovery snapshots.
#BACKUP_LIMIT=5
```

The BACKUP_LIMIT is the default as shown above.

systemctl list-timers shows:

```
Mon 2018-02-05 19:20:13 EST  53min left    Mon 2018-02-05 18:20:13 EST  6min ago     asd-resync.timer             asd-resync.service
```

How do I tell asd to make backup snapshots?